# Find subset with maximum score meeting constraint

Tags: algorithm, constraints, subset

Given a set of elements (text) with two features (length and score), give the maximum possible sum of one feature (score) having to meet a constraint on the other feature (length <= L_max).

e.g.

> 0: ("this is a text", 4, 0.5);
>
> 1: ("this is another", 3, 0.4);
>
> 2: ("this is the third element of the list", 8, 0.7)

The function I am searching for, with L_max = 8 should return elements 0 and 1.

I was thinking about a greedy solution. However, sorting by score does not give promising results. Can anyone give me a direction?

Comment: It seems a typical *Knapsack problem*: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem

Comment: Right, thank you! Knapsack solves it